# my json file doesn't appear in my index swift

Tags: arrays, json, swift, xcode, dictionary

Here I have a new problem:
My application compiles but unfortunately, I can't open the files contained in the json file. My indexViewController file doesn't display it.

Here is the link of my json file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qMKLNcf1fvYla21Yhh_D36FuPI-0-kj2/view?usp=drivesdk
and here is the code of my indexviewcontroller:  https://drive.google.com/file/d/169H5w6WvqAE43B4VceXqvSrHJXJUzE8Y/view?usp=sharing

Please help me I am still a beginner in Swift programming

```
class IndexViewController: UIViewController,  UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UISearchBarDelegate{
    
    @IBOutlet weak var indexTableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var bookmarkButton: UIBarButtonItem!
    
    // The BookViewModel init method decodes the json file and sets the chapters property on this instance
    var book: BookViewModel = BookViewModel()
    var chapters: [ChapterViewModel] = [ChapterViewModel]()
    var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext!
    
    var hasUserTappedOnBookmarkWidget: Bool = false
    
    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    var filteredChapters: [ChapterViewModel] = [ChapterViewModel]()
    var chapNumberAndSearchTextRangeList: [Int: [ChapterViewModel]] = [Int: [ChapterViewModel]]()
    var searching = false
    lazy var workItem = WorkItem()
    
    private var userClickedChapter: ChapterViewModel?
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        
        chapters = book.chapters
        setNavBarLargeTitleProperty()
        
        // This makes the table view row animate its selection state as it pops and pushes on the navigation stack.
        if let selectedIndex = indexTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            
            let coordinator = self.transitionCoordinator

            if coordinator != nil {
                coordinator?.animate(alongsideTransition: { (context) in
                    self.indexTableView.deselectRow(at: selectedIndex, animated: true)

                }, completion: { (context) in

                    if context.isCancelled {
                        self.indexTableView.selectRow(at: selectedIndex, animated: false, scrollPosition: .none)
                    } else {
                        self.indexTableView.deselectRow(at: selectedIndex, animated: true)
                    }
                })
            } else {
                self.indexTableView.deselectRow(at: selectedIndex, animated: true)
            }
        }
        
        // if the user has tapped on the widget, navigate to BookmarkViewController directly
        if hasUserTappedOnBookmarkWidget {
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToBookmarks", sender: self)
        }
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // Set the datasource and delegate as self
        indexTableView.dataSource = self
        indexTableView.delegate = self
        
        indexTableView.register(UINib(nibName: "IndexCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "customIndexCell")
```

Comment: Questions that require reviewing content on a website or other external source are off-topic here. When a link becomes obsolete, the question is no longer useful to future readers. We are trying to build a lasting repository of useful question/answer pairs here. Please review [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/) for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSON you posted is an invalid JSON, try validating your JSON in [some online linter](https://jsonlint.com) to see if your JSON is in correct format. After validation and making some changes, your JSON should look something [like this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1n-mWmlxIxG-IvswjN2zAS2gjZTMLHDo_/view?usp=sharing). (Since your JSON is too large It is uploaded on disk and you cannot check the preview directly on SO page :/ ) Afterwards check the decoder to make sure your object is decoded properly. From the JSON you posted you can decode `Book` object that has following structure:

```
struct Book {
  let name: String?
  let chapters: [Chapter]?
}

struct Chapter {
  let number: Int?
  let name, contents: String?
}
```